# Smooth resize using Titanium's ImageView?

Tags: image, resize, titanium, antialiasing

Simple problem: I have an image that's 200px x 200px, and I want to scale it down to show in an `ImageView` that's 60px x 60px.

Of course, Titanium resizes the image no problem, but it doesn't anti-alias it. The image is jagged.

Is there a way to tell Titanium so *smoothly* resize the image? Perhaps a way to force it to use one of the devices native methods like `setMagnificationFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the free image factory module?

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4973?1276408235